# How to get a list of password protected *.xlsx files in a directory containing many Excel files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, dir

Is there a way to see if *.xlsx files in a folder are password protected by reading the directory?

**Example directory text file**

1.xlsx
2.xlsx
3.xlsx
4.xlsx

**Example results text file**

1.xlsx - protected
2.xlsx
3.xlsx - protected
4.xlsx

I basically want to see which ones out of my directory are password protected without trying to open them. I am wondering if there is a directory switch. This is on a Windows machine by the way.

Comment: what do you mean with encrypted? NTFS encryption or password protected files?

Comment: @npocmaka password protected files

Comment: This might give you some clues: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML -- something with "unzip" may work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only work for OOXML files. As this kind of files are ZIP files, the first two bytes in the file are `PK` unless the file is password protected.

So, assumming all the files to process are office OOXML files, let's test if the first character in the file is a `P`. To capture this character, we will use a `xcopy /w`, that will wait for a keypress and echo this keypress. To capture the first character, simply redirect the file as the input to the xcopy, so, the keypress will be the first character in the file. If this character is a `P` the file is not password protected.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in (*.xlsx) do (
        call :isOfficeFilePasswordProtected "%%a" 
        if errorlevel 1 (
            echo %%a
        ) else (
            echo %%a - protected
        )
    )
    exit /b

:isOfficeFilePasswordProtected file
    if not exist "%~1" exit /b 1
    if %~z1 lss 1  exit /b 1
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "id=" & for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        xcopy /l /w "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>nul ^<"%~1" 
    ') do if not defined id set "id=%%a"
    if "%id:~-1%"=="P" ( set "exitCode=1" ) else ( set "exitCode=0" )
    endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```

Comment: this worked and was very helpful..I have a question...the part 'isOfficeFilePasswordProtected' where does this come from?

Comment: @JDE876, i had to name it. Offices encrypts the files when they are password protected, so ... But it is a subroutine, name it as you want.